# Color a string in Textmate?

Tags: colors, textmate

is it possible to display a certain string in Textmate in a custom color?

Lets say I want to display the string "myCoolFunction()" always in yellow so I can see better where I use the function in my documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it was possible. I modified the language pack. I am working with JavaScript so I edited the JavaScript language pack in TextMate. You have to create a new scope selector with a simple regex. After that you can create a new color rule in the settings and there you have it.

Answer (score 0):

No, there aren't any syntax selectors for specific functions.